# ¿Qué forma verbal usamos cuando imaginamos situaciones ante personas a las que hablamos de usted?

Tags: gramática, tiempos-verbales, persona-gramatical

Imaginad la situación siguiente: estás hablando con una persona mayor y quieres hacer una frase impersonal del tipo hipotético. Por ejemplo:

> Es como si comes un plato de lentejas y luego te pones a saltar.

En ese momento estás utilizando los verbos *comer* y *poner* en segunda persona del singular.

Sin embargo, me pregunto: si esa persona con la que hablas es lo suficiente mayor como para hablarle de usted, ¿deberían hacerse estas construcciones hipotéticas usando la expresión en términos de usted? Es decir, ¿debería cambiar la frase anterior por la siguiente?

> Es como si *come* un plato de lentejas y luego *se pone* a saltar.

Comment: Yo lo ajustaría: Es como si usted come un plato de lentejas y luego se pone a saltar.

Answer (score 2):

> Es como si comes un plato de lentejas y luego te pones a saltar.

También se puede decir: *es como si comiese lentejas y luego se pusiera a saltar*; o *es como si comiera lentejas y se pusiera a saltar*; o *es como si usted comiera lentejas y se pusiera a saltar*.

En realidad hay muchísimas formas en las que se puede construir esta oración, pero básicamente tu ejemplo, aunque gramáticamente correcto, suena un tanto "forzado." Quizá añadirle el pronombre "usted" hace que la oración fluya con más sintonía.

Answer (score 1):

Sí, netamente por el un tema de respeto para que no se pase a *tutear*. Básicamente estás omitiendo el usted en cada cláusula:

> Es como si (*usted*) coma un plato de lentejas y luego se ponga a saltar.

Aunque esto lo he visto más escrito con el imperfecto:

> Es como si (*usted*) **comiera/comiese** un plato de lentejas y luego se **pusiera/pusiese** a saltar.

Comment: Es valido también agregar que esta ultima forma verbal que utilizas tiene dos formas validas:                                                                                     > Es como si (_usted_) **comiera** / **comiese** un plato de lentejas y luego se **pusiera** / **pusiese** a saltar.

Comment: La primera versión no es correcta. La segunda sí.

Comment: @rsanchez Tenía un verbo en indicativo, ahí lo arreglé.

Comment: @Marco Sí, obviamente van las dos formas. Ya lo edité.

Comment: ¡Gracias por la respuesta! Entonces, ¿cuando utilizamos esta construcción debemos adaptarla a la persona con quien hablamos? Me explico: en estos casos para mí el decir _"es como si comes"_ es un recurso para definir un caso hipotético, pero no refiriéndome a esa persona sino en general. No sé si me explico.

Comment: @fedorqui En efecto, todo depende de la situación.

Comment: @fedorqui Aún siendo ese caso hipotético construido de forma general, seguiría siendo válido el usar "comiera/comiese" ya que se entendería, "Es como si (alguien) comiera/comiese y luego (ese alguien) se pusiera a saltar".

Comment: @JoseMaria de acuerdo. Sin embargo, mi duda persista: ¿hablar de esta forma implica adaptar la forma al interlocutor? Es decir, si estoy hablando con un grupo de personas, a mí me suena bien decir _"es como si comes..."_ para narrar algo hipotético, mientras que lo que apuntáis es que se debe adaptar y decir _"es como si coméis..."_.